# generate Json file from Neo4j DB to visualize the graph on the browser

Tags: json, neo4j

I get all nodes on the json file but I didn't find the relationships. I get null value even if my BD is full. Could you please help me?

Comment: Could you edit with more detail?  The query that you're using and how you're trying to visualize the JSON?

Answer (score 1):

In case you're getting the JSON through the REST [Transactional end point](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format) you may ask to return your result as `graph` format, so with both nodes and links.

More in general @micheal-hunger answer is right as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps explain in more detail what you want? You can export the JSON from a graph query for further processing.

If you want to visualize the results of a cypher query on your own, check this out: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization